# Button color not working , tkinter Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am learning Python. I use tkinter for gui.

I am unable to set foreground and background color in a button.

```
import sys

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sandwich")

root.geometry("500x250+800+100")

def helloButton():
    print('hello button')

myLabel1 = tk.Label(text="Label one",fg='red',bg='green').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='w')

myButton1 = tk.Button(text="Enter",activebackground='red',bg="blue",command=helloButton).grid(row=0,column=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Button does not shows foreground and background color when render.
Please advice.
[image]

Comment: It seems to work for me, can you post a picture of what is happening for you?

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: @Lafexlos Yes it appears to be that it does not work on a Mac. The same code gives a blue button, which when pressed is red as wanted, on Windows.

Comment: To get it to work, you should use `ttk` and create a style for it.

Comment: @jamescampbell Can you explain that a bit more? 

I'm so lost why this doesn't work on Mac